# spring security + rest doesn't work

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, basic-authentication

I have configured all properties, but my app still loads without spring security as if it does not exist... Please help me, what I am doing wrong.

Here I get my rooms without auth with postman:

[image]

Here below are my classes:

SecurityConfiguration:

```
package com.vidaflo.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("com.vidaflo")
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("bill").password("abc123").roles("ADMIN");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("tom").password("abc123").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/room/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

SecurityInitializer:

```
package com.vidaflo.config;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

WebConfiguration:

```
package com.vidaflo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.vidaflo.controllers")
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
}
```

Tomcat embedded:

```
package com.vidaflo.server;

import com.vidaflo.config.ApplicationConfiguration;
import com.vidaflo.config.DatabaseConfiguration;
import com.vidaflo.config.SecurityConfiguration;
import com.vidaflo.config.WebConfiguration;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

@Slf4j
public class Application {
    private static final String APPLICATION_PROPERTIES = System.getProperty("app.properties");
    private static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 8080;
    private static final String DEFAULT_CONTEXT_PATH = "/app";

    private AppProperties appProperties;
    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LifecycleException {
        Application app = new Application(APPLICATION_PROPERTIES);
        Server server = new TomcatServer(new Tomcat());
        app.run(server);
    }

    public Application(String fieldName) {
        loadProperties(fieldName);
    }

    public void run(Server server) {
        initApplicationContext();
        server.run(getConfig());
    }

    private void loadProperties(String fieldName) {
        appProperties = new AppProperties();
        appProperties.load(fieldName);
    }

    private void initApplicationContext() {
        log.info("Initialize application context...");

        ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(SecurityConfiguration.class);
        ctx.register(ApplicationConfiguration.class);
        ctx.register(WebConfiguration.class);
        ctx.register(DatabaseConfiguration.class);
        ctx.getEnvironment()
            .getPropertySources()
            .addLast(new PropertiesPropertySource("applicationEnvironment", appProperties.getProperties()));
    }

    private ServerConfig getConfig() {
        ServerConfig serverConfig = new ServerConfig();
        serverConfig.setPort(appProperties.getPort(DEFAULT_PORT));
        serverConfig.setContextPath(appProperties.getContextPath(DEFAULT_CONTEXT_PATH));
        serverConfig.setServlet(getServlet());
        return serverConfig;
    }

    private DispatcherServlet getServlet() {
        return new DispatcherServlet(ctx);
    }
}
```

Rest controller:

```
package com.vidaflo.controllers;

import com.vidaflo.dto.RoomDto;
import com.vidaflo.model.location.Room;
import com.vidaflo.repositories.LocationRepository;
import com.vidaflo.services.RoomService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@RestController
public class RoomController {
    @Autowired
    private RoomService roomService;

    @Autowired
    private LocationRepository locationService;

    @PostMapping("/room/save")
    public String save(@RequestParam(name = "name") String name,
                       @RequestParam(name = "location_id") Long locationId) {
        roomService.save(name, locationService.findOne(locationId));
        return "room added";
    }

    @GetMapping("/room/all")
    public List<RoomDto> findAll() {
        return roomService.findAll().stream()
                .map(this::toDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private RoomDto toDto(Room room) {
        return RoomDto.builder()
                .id(room.getId())
                .name(room.getName())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Please tell me if I should add additional details. I rly need help and I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @KimAragonEscobar yes I have tried`"/**"` and a lot others but it still doesn't work

Comment: I add `@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})` (also I've tried `@Secured("ADMIN")` ) to controller method and I add `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)` to SecurityConfiguration class, but now I have an exception `security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext` ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer, we should manually add filter for spring security in tomcat embedded config like this:

```
FilterDef filterDef = new FilterDef();
        filterDef.setFilterName("springSecurityFilterChain");
        filterDef.setFilterClass("org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy");
        container.addFilterDef(filterDef);

        FilterMap filterMapping = new FilterMap();
        filterMapping.setFilterName("springSecurityFilterChain");
        filterMapping.addURLPattern("/*");
        container.addFilterMap(filterMapping);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to change role "ADMIN" "USER" to "ROLE_ADMIN" "ROLE_USER" in configureGlobalSecurity method and in the enum "Roles", but in configure method don't change.

Comment: we may not use roles with prefix `ROLE_` in `configure global security method` . Well, I've tried and got exception: `ROLE_ADMIN cannot start with ROLE_ (it is automatically added)